# How to instruct ant build tool to include another project's files in build.xml

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

I have two projects in my Eclipse ADT Android workspace

```
MyProject
MyProjectUITests
```

I have included `MyProject` in `MyProjectUITests` build path, so I can use a constants class from `MyProject`

Then I do the following (this is a .bat file of CMD commands):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
e:
CD \adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\tools\
CALL android create uitest-project -n automated_tests -t 16 -p C:\Users\Jofh\Desktop\MyProject\MyProject\automated_tests"
c:
CD "\Users\Jofh\Desktop\MyProject\MyProject\automated_tests"
CALL ant build
CALL adb push "C:\Users\Jofh\Desktop\MyProject\MyProject\automated_tests\bin\automated_tests.jar" /data/local/tmp
CALL adb shell uiautomator runtest automated_tests.jar -c com.example.myproject.automated.AppTest
pause
```

Now, including one of the projects in the other project's build path was enough to compile the project in Eclipse, but when I run this script I get an error message saying the classes from MyProject dont exist.

I read on the internet that I had to include MyProject in the build.xml file when I build via `ant build` but how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) target like:

```
<ant antfile="myOtherBuildFile" target="mytarget" />
```

Comment: Where do I insert this line of code and what should the values of myOtherBuildFile and mytarget be?

Comment: So this means that from second build file for project, you may have build target, so you could define this statement before building the second project.

Answer (score 0):

> I have included MyProject in MyProjectUITests build path, so I can use a constants class from MyProject

So suppose you have added `MyProject` as library to your `MyProjectUITests`. Then you do not need add `MyProject` to `build.xml` of `MyProjectUITests`, because `MyProject` has been defined in the `project.properties` of `MyProjectUITests`. Then you just need create `build.xml` for `MyProject` if you have not done it.

To create `build.xml` for `MyProject`, just from command line go to the root of `MyProject`, and run `android update project -p .`

Now you can run `ant clean release` under the root of `MyProjectUITests`

Comment: MyProject isnt marked as `is library` in properties, so it is not a library for MyProjectUITests, it is just in the build path. Does that change anything?

Comment: so you did not add `MyProject` as library project to your `MyProjectUITests`? then how could your `MyProjectUITests` uses classes of `MyProject`

Comment: it is in the Build path as a project